# How would I graph this polar equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$r=-2cos\theta $$

Steps I took:

$$r^{ 2 }=-2x$$

$$x^{ 2 }+y^2=-2x$$

$$x^{ 2 }+y^{ 2 }+2x=0$$

Usually I can complete these problems by completing the square in order to find the equation of the circle but I don't think I can do anything with:

$$x^{ 2 }+(y^{ 2 }+2x+1)=0+1$$

Comment: First of all, shouldn't it be $r=-2\cos\theta$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now want to say $x^2+2x+y^2=0$. Complete the square:
$$x^2+2x+1+y^2=0+1$$
which gives you $$(x+1)^2+y^2=1.$$
This is the equation of your circle, with center $(-1,0)$ and radius $1$.

Comment: For some reason that didn't pop out to me right away. Thank you.